# How to put multiple imshow() results in one figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to plot all the iterations in one plot for the matrix `syn0`, but the following code is showing just the last iteration and if I change the code it will open the plot 60000 times, how can I plot all the iteration in just one plot?

```
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((3, 4)) - 1

arr_syn0[0][0].append(syn0[0][0])
arr_syn0[0][1].append(syn0[0][1])
arr_syn0[0][2].append(syn0[0][2])
arr_syn0[0][3].append(syn0[0][3])
arr_syn0[1][0].append(syn0[1][0])
arr_syn0[1][1].append(syn0[1][1])
arr_syn0[1][2].append(syn0[1][2])
arr_syn0[1][3].append(syn0[1][3])
arr_syn0[2][0].append(syn0[2][0])
arr_syn0[2][1].append(syn0[2][1])
arr_syn0[2][2].append(syn0[2][2])
arr_syn0[2][3].append(syn0[2][3])


plt.figure()
x=plt.imshow(syn0,aspect='auto', interpolation="nearest", cmap='YlOrRd_r', origin="upper")
plt.colorbar(x)
plt.title('syn1')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use subplots to do that kind of thing

Comment: Why are you appending the elements of `syn0` to another array (`arr_syn0`)? Wasn't it possible to just use `syn0`? Also I do not see any iteration in this code...

Comment: Even if I do not see any iteration when you open a figure (`plt.figure()`) a new figure will be created. If you want to re-use the same figure open it once (e.g. put the operation outside the loop).

Comment: it's not the whole code (for j in range(60000):) and i'm appendig the elements because I need to save all the iterations in a vector(arr_syn0 = [[[],[],[],[]], [[],[],[],[]], [[],[],[],[]]])

Comment: If I put the operation outside the loop it opens a new window for every iteration, and i have deleted (plt.figure()) @toti08

Comment: @andree17914can you please post the whole code? Or an excerpt but that gives an idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to see the weights, and how they change, actually only syn0

Comment: What is `nonlin` in your code?

Comment: it's the sigmoid function @toti08

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to plot all the iterations in one plot, but since you're iterating over 60000 images I guess what you want is to plot the new data on the same figure without opening a new one.

In order to do that you should use the `imshow` method on the first image only, and use the [`draw`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html) method on the other images, followed by the [`pause`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html) method that will call the GUI event loop and update the image.

Trying to reduce your code to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'd do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

firstImage = True

for j in range(5): 
    syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((3, 4)) - 1
    if firstImage:    
        img=plt.imshow(syn0,aspect='auto', interpolation="nearest", cmap='YlOrRd_r', origin="upper") 
        firstImage = False
    else:
        img.set_data(syn0)
        plt.pause(0.1)
        plt.draw()
    plt.title('syn1')
```

This code shows the different images on the same figure one after the other.
Hope this helps.